# Closed question still allows answers to be added

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, closed-questions

[This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10427/how-do-you-make-a-person-quit-using-the-word-like) was closed at 1:29. Yet, at 2:10 a new answer was posted. See the [timeline](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/10427/timeline). How is that even possible?

Comment: Yeah, that is weird!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a question is closed, there is a [grace period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38228) (of 4 hours, see comment below) during which you can still post an answer.

Comment: Heh. That had crossed my mind, actually; if it takes someone 40 minutes to compose an answer, he sure does deserve to be allowed to post it.

Comment: #2 is not correct. There is now a grace period but it is several hours. I just checked the code and it is 4 hours to be exact.

Comment: @Jeff Atwood: Out of curiosity, what is the grace period for?

Comment: @kosmo we felt it was cruel if someone wrote a great 4 paragraph response, and couldn't answer because the question was closed, even though they didn't know that during the entire composition of their answer. It could in theory be reopened too.

Comment: @Jeff Atwood: Okay, makes sense.

Comment: @Jeff Atwood: I ended up here following Reg's comment under [Reopening prematurely Closed questions](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2463/). I think either the code you refer to doesn't exist any more, or it doesn't work as intended. I just waited until a suitable *"question likely to be closed soon"* turned up (easy done here on ELU these days!), and started typing into the "Your Answer" box. When it did get closed soon after, I got all sorts of trouble (including a Capcha), but no way was it going to let me post my answer!